# When to show the data get error Tried to bind parameter number 2101. SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel, sqlsrv

I get an error when user open their homepage. before this everything is working. I'm using Laravel and SQL Server. Total data to show is 1574 rows.

> SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Tried to bind parameter number 2101. SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. (SQL: select * from [table] where [table].[id(1,2,3)] in

Here is my controller to show the data:

```
public function show() {
    $user = User::wherein('status', ['2','3','4','5','6','7','99'])->orderBy('date','DESC')->get();

    return view('dca_admin.index',compact('user'));
}
```

Here is my `views.blade`:

```
@foreach ($user as $user)
     <tr>
        <td>{{$user->Detail->name }}</td>
        <td>{{$user->status }}</td>
        <td>{{$user->remark }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

And my database configuration:

```
'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'xxxx'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' =>secEnv('DB_DATABASE', 'xxx'),
        'username' =>secEnv('DB_USERNAME', 'xxx'),
        'password' =>secEnv('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => false,
    ],
```

I found is it related to sql server side
**Parameters per user-defined function  maximum 2,100**
so its mean i only can to show/get 2100 data? Is it?

But I tried in local with 4000 data, i dont get this error, the page only load slowly.
How to resolve this?

Comment: did you try whereIn with the uppercase "I"?

Comment: IMSSP is a driver error. What php version are you using, and what driver?

Comment: before this, the code is work. is it related to total data?

Comment: apache php 7.4. redhat and ms sql 2019

Comment: and what driver php to connect ms sql ?

Comment: 'driver' => 'sqlsrv', i just edited my question

Comment: i try to get limit the data limit(200) but still get the same error

Comment: The driver on server, not in laravel. Are you using freeds? or some similar? I think it's a wrong setting on the OS driver.